# Appending dictionary to JSON file without overwriting every time

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file like this :

```
{
  "objects": [
    {
      "obj_id": 0,
      "file_name": "xyz"
    },
     {
      "obj_id": 1,
      "file_name": "pqr"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to append another dictionary to objects list directly without doing like this:

```
data_object = {
      "obj_id": 2,
      "file_name": "stu"
    }

# Read the entire file.
with open(fp, 'r') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

# Update the data read.
credentials = data['objects']
credentials.append(data_object)

# Update the file by rewriting it.
with open(fp, 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(data, json_file, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

With this I am opening the file each time just to append one single dictionary. Is there a way around this where I can append a dictionary directly to the file without rewriting the contents each time ??

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `w` which overwrites, use `a` which is like `append`.

```
with open(fp, 'a') as json_file:
```

Comment: Even with this I have to load the data every time and then write it to file...Is there a way to append that dictionary directly to file without loading previous data first ??